# Search a vector of boost::tuple

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tuples

Is there an algorithm or helper method in the boost library to search a vector of `boost::tuple` objects? Here is my code:

```
typedef boost::tuple<int, char const*, char const*> Tuple;
typedef std::vector<Tuple> ErrorStringMap;

ErrorStringMap mystrings = tuple_list_of
    (10, "10", "ten") 
    (20, "20", "twenty") 
    (30, "30", "thirty") 
    (40, "40", "fourty");
```

I want to search the vector of tuples and find the first tuple with the value 20 as the first element in the tuple. I want to access that tuple's 2nd and 3rd elements.

Comment: If you're always looking up the element by the first element, consider using an `(unordered_)map` instead.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::find_if`?

Comment: @ildjarn I'd have to write my own functor for it, I believe. I was hoping boost already had a helper method that would return a reference to the tuple instead of an iterator (easier to work with). I can write my own solution easily enough I just wanted to make sure boost didn't have anything for this first.

Comment: I suppose you could do `std::find_if(mystrings.begin(), mystrings.end(), boost::bind(&Tuple::get<0>, _1) == 20)` instead of writing an entire functor... [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/) may allow for something slightly cleaner, but I'm not aware of anything specific offhand.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm using boost lambda's bind, to implement your example, but I get: `error C2660: 'bind' : function does not take 2 arguments`

Comment: That sounds like you're picking up the wrong `bind`. Try fully qualifying it as well as the placeholder. (And Boost.Lambda is dead -- use Boost.Phoenix instead.)

Comment: @ildjarn I use boost.phoenix now and that specific error went away, now it says it can't find `_1`. I even do `using boost::phoenix::_1` and it still says undeclared identifier?

Comment: [Phoenix's placeholders are in `boost::phoenix::placeholders`](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/core/arguments.html). Also, if you're using Phoenix, you don't need `bind` for this -- with the proper includes, `at_c<0>(_1) == 20` works.

Comment: @ildjarn: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @GManNickG : I don't feel like typing all the details needed for a _proper_ answer. You can post it, I'll be happy to upvote it. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: What if I'm just as lazy? :) I will sometime soon if nobody else does.

Comment: Guys, I need something to mark as an answer. ildjarn, please put something as an answer, even something short & sweet. I'll accept it, whatever you put. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ildjarn answered this in the list of comments below my question, however he did not post as an answer, so I will do it for him:

> Phoenix's placeholders are in boost::phoenix::placeholders. Also, if
>   you're using Phoenix, you don't need bind for this -- with the proper
>   includes, at_c<0>(_1) == 20 works.